# Use of sqrt link with negative binomial glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, link-function

It doesn't seem to be directly possible to use a sqrt link function in lme4::glmer.nb. This is a pity because on my specific data, with the fix effect model, the sqrt link does improve the distribution of the residuals.

Looking at the code it seems that simply adding a `link="sqrt"` within the calls of `negative.binomial` in the `lme4::glmer.nb` function and in the `lme4:::setNBdisp` hidden function would do the trick.

After doing it, it does spit something out that is different from the standard and does seem quite coherent. Is there any reason this would be an heresy?

The quick an dirty lines I added to my script that do just that (I'm happy enough with it to publish results based on it).

```
# machinery to add a glmer.nb.sqrt function
#=========================================

est_theta <- lme4:::est_theta
glmNB.to.change <- lme4:::glmNB.to.change
getNBdisp <- lme4:::getNBdisp

setNBdisp.sqrt <- function (object, theta,link) 
{
    rr <- object@resp
    newresp <- do.call(glmResp$new, c(lapply(setNames(nm = glmNB.to.change), 
                                         rr$field), list(family = negative.binomial(theta = theta,
                                                                                        link="sqrt"))))
    newresp$setOffset(rr$offset)
    newresp$updateMu(rr$eta - rr$offset)
    object@resp <- newresp
    object
}
refitNB.sqrt <- function (object, theta, control = NULL) 
{
    refit(setNBdisp.sqrt(object, theta), control = control)
}

optTheta.sqrt <- function (object, interval = c(-5, 5), 
                             tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, 
                         verbose = FALSE, control = NULL) 
{
lastfit <- object
it <- 0L
NBfun <- function(t) {
    dev <- -2 * logLik(lastfit <<- refitNB.sqrt(lastfit, theta = exp(t), 
        control = control))
    it <<- it + 1L
    if (verbose) 
        cat(sprintf("%2d: th=%#15.10g, dev=%#14.8f, beta[1]=%#14.8f\n", 
            it, exp(t), dev, lastfit@beta[1]))
    dev
}
optval <- optimize(NBfun, interval = interval, tol = tol)
stopifnot(all.equal(optval$minimum, log(getNBdisp(lastfit))))
attr(lastfit, "nevals") <- it
lastfit@call$family[["theta"]] <- exp(optval$minimum)
lastfit
}
glmer.nb.sqrt <- function (..., interval = log(th) + c(-3, 3), 
                        tol = 5e-05, verbose = FALSE, 
                        nb.control = NULL, 
                        initCtrl = list(limit = 20, eps = 2 * tol, trace = verbose, theta = NULL)) 
{
link="sqrt"
dotE <- as.list(substitute(E(...))[-1])
mc <- match.call()
if (is.null(th <- initCtrl$theta)) {
    mc[[1]] <- quote(glmer)
    mc$family <- quote(stats::poisson)
    mc$verbose <- (verbose >= 2)
    g0 <- eval(mc, parent.frame(1L))
    th <- est_theta(g0, limit = initCtrl$limit, eps = initCtrl$eps, 
        trace = initCtrl$trace)
    if (verbose) 
        cat("th := est_theta(glmer(..)) =", format(th))
}
mc$initCtrl <- NULL
mc$family <- bquote(negative.binomial(theta = .(th),link=.(link)))
g1 <- eval(mc, parent.frame(1L))
if (verbose) 
    cat(" --> dev.= -2*logLik(.) =", format(-2 * logLik(g1)), 
        "\n")
if ("data" %in% names(g1@call)) {
    if (!is.null(dotE[["data"]])) {
        g1@call[["data"]] <- dotE[["data"]]
    }
}
else warning("no 'data = *' in glmer.nb() call ... Not much is guaranteed")
other.args <- c("verbose", "control")
for (a in other.args) {
    if (a %in% names(g1@call)) {
        g1@call[[a]] <- dotE[[a]]
    }
}
optTheta.sqrt(g1, interval = interval, tol = tol, verbose = verbose, 
    control = c(eval.parent(g1@call$control), nb.control))
}
```